# Using iptables without root privileges

Tags: linux, iptables, redhat, apache-2.2, amazon-linux

When running the following script as user `ec2-user`, I get the error message `iptables v1.4.18: can't initialize iptables table filter: Permission denied (you must be root)`

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Offending IP as detected by mod_evasive
# Add the following firewall rule (block IP)
$IPTABLES -I INPUT -s $IP -j DROP
```

How can I run `iptables` as a non-root user to block a IP address?

NB: This script is usually called by mod_evasive

Comment: Be very careful with that, be sure that `$IPTABLES` var is the right absolute path to the binary.

Comment: @XavierLucas: The path is correct: "IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"

Answer (score 3):

Set the setuid bit on the script, so that it always runs as root.

```
chown root myscript
chmod u+s myscript
```

Comment: Hi Michael, when trying to run the script, I do get the error message: command not found. What permissions would I need to change? Any idea?

Comment: What command is not found?

Comment: The script itself: When I enter the command in bash: "sudo ban_ip.sh 94.201.234.1xx", I do get: "sudo: ban_ip.sh: command not found". But the script file is there.

Comment: @AlexR Why are you trying to sudo ? Also if it's not in your `PATH` you need to use the absolute path `./ban_ip.sh`.

Comment: @XavierLucas: With or without sudo: It does not work. I am in the same directory as the script when trying to execute it.

Comment: You are not using the **absolute path**. It doesn't matter in which directory you are.

Answer (score 1):

Based on another comment you made here the issue you're experiencing is bash cannot find the script you are trying to run.

When you are running a script or command that isn't in one of the paths defined in your `$PATH` environment setting you need to provide the absolute or relative path for it. For example:

- If the script is in `/usr/local/bin` you need to run `/usr/local/bin/scriptname.sh`.
- If the script is in your home directory you need to run either `/home/username/scriptname.sh` or `~/scriptname.sh`.
- Alternatively you can change into that directory and call it with `./` like so:  `./scriptname.sh`

Also you can update your `$PATH` environment setting with the path to the script by modifying `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, or `.profile`, depending on what env file you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Just add sudo before the command:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Offending IP as detected by mod_evasive
# Add the following firewall rule (block IP)
sudo $IPTABLES -I INPUT -s $IP -j DROP
```

Comment: using sudo to gain root privileges is not the same as accomplishing the task without root privileges...

Answer (score 0):

If your script is:

```
/drop.sh
```

and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s "$1" -j DROP
```

Then add a line to your `/etc/sudoers` file that looks something like:

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /drop.sh
```

NB if Apache is running as a user besides `www-data` you'll need to use that username here. This lets the Apache user run your drop.sh

Then finally a wrapper for `mod_evasive`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sudo /drop.sh "$@"
```

Comment: What's the point putting the script at the root of the filesystem ? Also, you should always use `visudo` wrapper instead of editing any sudoers file, that's why it's read-only by default.

Comment: You can put files wherever you want, but then you need to explain that all the other paths need to change.